# Dynamic function calls in php for SMS Syntax patterns Definition

Tags: php, syntax, user-controls, pattern-matching, sms

For an IoT project [I'm showing here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/107923/sms-gateway-project-using-zte-4g-modem) in the Raspberry forum, I'm trying to define a syntax for SMS commands. 
I started with the following folder structure:

```
├── assets/
│   ├── css/ ...
│   └── js/ ...
│
│   
├── lib/
│   ├── modemClass.php
│   └── smsClass.php
├─ config.ini
│ 
└─ commands.php
```

, allowing advanced users to define their own equipment's APIs and simplify SMS commands definition by modifying two files:

**config.ini** to update global constants that would be parsed when needed in phpClasses:

```
ip=192.168.1.xxx
timeZone=+1
pwd=admin
smsKey=MYPWD
```

**commands.php** : Inspired from wordpress (functions.php) structure, this file would allow SMS syntax configuration and commands definition...

```
require_once('lib/modemClass.php');
$modem=new Mifi;
$commands = array();
$commands['REBOOT']['PI']='rebootPi';
$commands['REBOOT']['MODEM']='rebootModem';
$commands['SEND']['EMAIL']='sendEmail';
$commands['SET']['LIGHT']='setLight';
$commands['SET']['GARAGE']='setGarage';
$commands['SEND']['TEMP']='sendTemperature';
function rebootModem(){
    echo 'Modem will reboot!';
}
function setGarage($args){
    echo 'Garage would become: '.$args;
}
function sendTemperature($modem){
    $modem=new Mifi;
    $modem->check_modem();
    $modem->send(<SENDERNUMBER>,"Pi checks Sensor  Welcome API !");
}

function setLight($args){
    $lg=explode("#",$args);
    echo 'Light would become "'.$lg[1].'" in the '.$lg[0];
}

function sendEmail($sms){
    $filter= preg_split("/[\s]+/", $sms);
    $clean = array($filter[0],$filter[1],$filter[2]);
    $email=explode("#",str_replace($clean,'',$sms));
    echo 'smsTomail('.$email[0].','.$email[1].','.$email[2].')';
    //smsToEmail($email[0],$email[1],$email[2]);
}
```

**smsClass.php** : would handle SMS parsing, validation and trigger appropriate action (function) for the command following that predefined syntax.

```
<?php
include (ROOT_PATH.'/commands.php');
class smsHandle
{
    public function __construct() {
       $this->conf = parse_ini_file(ROOT_PATH.'/config.ini', true);
    }    

    public function parseSms($sms,$commands){
        $filter= preg_split("/[\s]+/", strtoupper($sms),4);
        if($filter[0]==$this->conf['smsKey']){
        if(array_key_exists($filter[1], $commands)){
            if(array_key_exists($filter[2], $commands[$filter[1]])){
                $args = $filter[3] ?? null;
                $args=($filter[2]=='EMAIL') ? $sms : $args;            
                call_user_func_array($commands[$filter[1]][$filter[2]], array(&$args));
            } else{
                echo 'TARGET is not identified!';
            }
        } else {
            echo 'Action Identifier is not clear!';
        }  

        } else {
            echo 'Unknown COMMAND ! PLZ verify your Syntax';            
        }        
    }
}
?>
```

A simplified syntax of sms commands would follow this pattern:

```
PASSWORD  SETACTION  TARGET  PARAMETERS/VALUES
```

And it could be:

```
PASSWORD GET TARGET DATA
```

Some electronic commands could logically expects extra parameters (arguments) while others don't!
So, I thought about using an array as a model, to verify the syntax and return it's matching function. Then in undefined extra levels, I test for exceptions... And I let the appropriate function deal with anomalies. Like the email case here that expects it's parameters to be separated by **#**

At the end usage would look like following:

```
$modem->check_modem();
$hand=new smsHandle;
//$sms='MYPWD SEND TEMP';
$sms='MYPWD
SET
LIGHT  GARDEN#ON';
$hand->parseSms($sms,$commands);
```

It's working ! but thinking about an easy customization, an extensible code and performance, is it the right approach to use dynamic call of functions in php to define commands' syntax? using arrays...

[UPDATE] For clarification, the presented code doesn't handle multiple commands parsing. And the  model could be extended with functions that could expect different arguments.
The question is more concerned about the efficiency of arrays for syntax definition and validation.

Comment: FYI: There is no need to write your `\s` in a character class.  But you need to cap the explosions to 4?  How should the arguments be delimited?

Comment: Are delimiters sometimes spaces and sometimes hash symbols?  Are the `$args` strings always preceded by `#`?  Perhaps you want `preg_match_all()` with `\G`.

Comment: Yes and  that's not a rule ! I just need to use hash symbols # to avoid confusion with commands pattern that follows array sub-levels order... Like in the email and GardenLight sample here

Comment: I am still trying to figure out what your exact intended parsed output will be for each sample sms.  https://3v4l.org/Atdub  Please clarify your question.

Comment: You think arguments should be limited? That's the point :) some functions need more arguments than others...

Comment: No, I meant the `preg_split()` should be limited so that an email message with spaces in the body doesn't make a million separate arguments.  Your whitelist of keywords can be built into the pattern to improve validation and extraction.  Please edit your question to show the quality and number of atguments you expect from the samples.

Comment: The output is always a function... like those "examples" I'm displaying here as a demo to clarify the idea.

Comment: Ok I'll take note of that, Thanks! so in order to treat the email case separately, use a delimiter like Brackets [...]

Comment: Thanks for noticing that :) I aimed to validate the email exception separately in it's appropriate function by sending the whole sms as an argument. But your remark could be useful for commands with similar patterns. So I added a limit 4 to preg_split ! I don't think a command could cross that limit... when it does, it should be handled separately.

Comment: I am happy to help you with this, but your concept/requirements need a lot of sharpening.  This is likely to be a never-ending question aka "a moving target" for volunteers. Please fully consider how your input strings may vary and how your application may grow so that your requirements are focused/clear.   How will the syntax be modified to support multiple commands?  Might your _Subject_  ever possibly be multiple words? If you maintain the white list of _Verbs_ and _Subjects_, how large do you think this will scale? Your answer to these are critical to developing a robust parsing technique.